# count number of occuranes in array based on another array in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays of objects and need to count how many times a value is used in another array.
So let's say I have persons that are assigned to tasks. There can be tasks without persons, persons without tasks, or tasks with multiple persons:

```
array1 = [
    {id: 1, user: 'John'},
    {id: 2, user: 'Melinda'},
    {id: 3, user: 'Carl'}
    {id: 4, user: 'Eddie'}
]
```

and tasks

```
array2 = [
    {id: 5, task: 'a', users: [1]}
    {id: 6, task: 'b', users: [2]}
    {id: 7, task: 'c', users: [2,3]}
    {id: 8, task: 'd', users: []}
]
```

And I need an array telling me the number of tasks a person has (there is no need to know which task it is, but if that's easier it would be ok as well)

```
array3 = [
    {id: 1, user: 'John', count: 1},
    {id: 2, user: 'Melinda', count: 2},
    {id: 3, user: 'Carl', count: 1}
    {id: 4, user: 'Eddie', count: 0}
]
```

or

```
array3 = [
    {id: 1, user: 'John', tasks: ['a']},
    {id: 2, user: 'Melinda', tasks: ['b','c']},
    {id: 3, user: 'Carl', tasks: ['c']}
    {id: 4, user: 'Eddie', tasks: []}
]
```

In Vanilla JS it would take a couple of loops to get through the array so I thought it would be easier and faster doing it in lodash, but could not figure out how to achieve this result with lodash. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be easier with lodash, but if done right certainly not faster.

Comment: What does your sample vanillajs implementation look like? Would you accept an answer that didn't use lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash has a convenient `_.countBy()` methods that produces an object in the form of `{ [key]: counts }`, so if you have lodash it would shorten your code a bit.

Use `Array.flatMap()` or (or lodash's `_.flatMap()`) on `tasks` to get an array of user ids, and then use `_.countBy()` to get an object of number of tasks per id. Now you can map the `users`, and take the number of tasks from the counts object.

```js
const users = [{"id":1,"user":"John"},{"id":2,"user":"Melinda"},{"id":3,"user":"Carl"},{"id":4,"user":"Eddie"}]
const tasks = [{"id":5,"task":"a","users":[1]},{"id":6,"task":"b","users":[2]},{"id":7,"task":"c","users":[2,3]},{"id":8,"task":"d","users":[]}]

const numTasksByUsers = _.countBy(tasks.flatMap(o => o.users))
const usersWithTasksCount = users.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  tasks: numTasksByUsers[o.id] ?? 0
}))

console.log(usersWithTasksCount)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you don't use lodash, you can easily create a `count` method using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const count = arr => arr.reduce((acc, o) => ({
  ...acc,
  [o]: (acc[o] ?? 0) + 1
}), {})

const users = [{"id":1,"user":"John"},{"id":2,"user":"Melinda"},{"id":3,"user":"Carl"},{"id":4,"user":"Eddie"}]
const tasks = [{"id":5,"task":"a","users":[1]},{"id":6,"task":"b","users":[2]},{"id":7,"task":"c","users":[2,3]},{"id":8,"task":"d","users":[]}]

const numTasksByUsers = count(tasks.flatMap(o => o.users))
const usersWithTasksCount = users.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  tasks: numTasksByUsers[o.id] ?? 0
}))

console.log(usersWithTasksCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla js solution:

1. Use `filter` with `includes` to get the tasks that the user is assigned to
2. Map the result to the name of the task

```
const usersWithTasks = users.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  tasks: tasks
    .filter((task) => task.users.includes(user.id))
    .map((task) => task.task),
}));
```

```js
const users = [
  { id: 1, user: "John" },
  { id: 2, user: "Melinda" },
  { id: 3, user: "Carl" },
  { id: 4, user: "Eddie" },
];

const tasks = [
  { id: 5, task: "a", users: [1] },
  { id: 6, task: "b", users: [2] },
  { id: 7, task: "c", users: [2, 3] },
  { id: 8, task: "d", users: [] },
];

const usersWithTasks = users.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  tasks: tasks
    .filter((task) => task.users.includes(user.id))
    .map((task) => task.task),
}));

console.log(usersWithTasks);
```